# wordpress- dynamically change webpage banner text by passing parameter in url

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am trying to change banner text of one of the web page according to the url parameter. Not sure which code should I modify. or use hook? please someone help me.
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out where that text is coming from.

Most WordPress templates that I have used allow you to change this on the admin screen (dashboard). If you log into WordPress using admin password and select Theme/Customize, you should be presented with several options that let you customize this.

There is also a Settings tab visible from the dashboard that lets you change the site name (if that is what's being displayed there).

If you cant find it in either of those, you can try to search for the text in the files system (under themes) and see what's returned.

Comment: I found that single_post_title() is setting the banner text for my web pages. but I can't find this function's definition to edit it

Comment: I found that function defined in a file called general-template.php in wp-includes folder. But the value itself is not being stored there.

Comment: Most likely its coming from the DB, which means its being set on one of the config pages in the admin dashboard that I mentioned earlier. Did you try logging in as admin and checking theme customizations ?

Comment: yes I checked theme customization, didn't found there.

Comment: What about the settings? The code appears to be reading the site title which should be set on the settings page.

Comment: I found the solution. Just modified one of the page template code. I needed to pass a parameter in single_post_title() function so that it prefixed page banner text